# How to display data from ajax response ( json type ) in Django template?

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, django

I am using Django Template for displaying data, in template i am calling ajax request like this :

```
{% for entry in entries %}

<script>
var ids = {{ entry }};
$.ajax({
     .......
     .......
    success: function (data) {
         alert(JSON.stringify(data));
      }
});
{% endfor %}
```

> Got data in json formate like :

```
[{"model":"main.mymodel","pk":258160,"fields":{"idn":920087058,"name":null,"ico":null,"street":"PO BOX 149","city":"HYDER","state":"AK","zip":"99923"}}]
```

I want to display in Table like **(In same template)** :

- idn-920087058
- name-null
- street-PO BOX 149
  ...

---

Comment: Why are you using Ajax for this, rather than passing the data directly to the template from the view?

Comment: actually i have multiple data (ids) at same click, i think fetch data from database as ajax request with that ids

Comment: try this JSON.parse(result)

Comment: Django template code is rendered on the server. If you want to render something from that data client side, you have to use javascript. If you really want to use django templates,  you can send prerendered html in an ajax request instead of json data.

Comment: @HåkenLid - I am getting back HTML data from ajax call back to the template. I am able to render the data by looping through the list (from which the HTML has been derived) using a loop in jQuery (but in plain rows/coluns without any css). What I am looking to do is to **display the HTML data in a table**.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>idn</tr>
        <tr>name</tr>
        <tr>street</tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="myTable"></tbody>
</table>

<script>
var = TableItem = ""

{% for entry in entries %}
var ids = {{ entry }};
$.ajax({
     .......
     .......
    success: function (data) {
         $.each(data, function(index, value){
             TableItem +='<tr>' +
                                '<td>'+value.fields.idn+'</td>' +
                                '<td>'+value.fields.name+'</td>' +
                                '<td>'+value.fields.street+'</td>' +
                            '</tr>'
            $('#myTable').html(TableContent);
         })
      }
});

{% endfor %}
```

I think one ajax query would be better.

```
ids = [{% for entry in entries %}{{ entry.id }}{% if forloop.last %}{% else %},{% endif %}{% endfor %}]
```